# EMI performances observed better for stripline routing with pth rather than stripline with blind via

Tags: pcb, emc, signal-integrity, via, pcb-simulation

The circuit is: A fast switching driver (Lvth buffer) is transmitting a signal to Leon processor receiver and it also has a series termination.

Stackup: top(L1), gnd, sig1(inner lyr3), 2.5V plane, sig2, sig3, gnd, 5v plane, sig4, sig5, 3.3V plane, sig6(inner lyr12), gnd, bottom(L14)

Routing: The components are mounted on top layer(driver, reciver and passive), hence the fanouts are only microstrip with 90% routing done in inner layer as stripline with 2 vias.( It is done deliberately to reduce the EMI levels in required frequency bands for the identified net)

So it is like, in top layer, fanout from Lvth driver connects series termination . From series termination fanout, the signal is dropped inner layer through a via.

In inner layer 90% of the routing happens here and then again through a 2nd via the signal goes back to top layer and connects the fanout of receiver.

Question:

Case I: The particular net was routed as stripline in inner layer-3 of 14 layer board with  blind via. Via impedance is 30ohm;. Electric field intensity is 29 udBV/m measured at 1 m form DUT.

Case II: Same net was routed as stripline in inner layer-12 with Pth via. Via impedance is 37ohm;. Electric field intensity is 24 udBV/m measured at 1 m form DUT.

Please note:

** In both the cases the net is sandwiched between reference planes on adjacent layer.

** Impedance in inner layer is 57ohm; and external layer is 52ohm; with a series termination of 33ohm.

Can someone clarify the reason? As I was expecting blind via to perform better due to reduction of via inductance.

Comment: You don't say where the signal comes from on the other side of the via.  Can you share a diagram that shows the complete signal path/layout?   Also you don't say in what way the EMI performance is "better" - can you please explain this in more detail.   Please edit the question to include this extra information.  That makes it easier for other people to help you.

Comment: I have updated it again. Unfortunately I can't share the original images pf any sort as it might cause confidentiality issues.

Comment: Are you saying that scenario 1 was active whilst scenario 2 was disabled then, you switched the active scenarios?

Comment: Where is your ground/return plane in this?  On what layers?  And we, or at least I, need to see a stackup.

Comment: @Andyaka    No. scenario 1 and scenario 2 are two different boards. Everything is same...I just transferred the routing in inner layer 12 with pth to inner layer 3 and changed the pth to blind and ran simulations

Comment: @SteveSh layers are top, gnd, sig1(inner lyr3), 2.5V plane, sig2, sig3, gnd, 5v plane, sig4, sig5, 3.3V plane, sig6(inner lyr12), gnd, bottom

Comment: OK, so you have some chip pin on L1 -> trace -> 33 ohm series resistor on L1 -> trace -> via (PTH or blind depending on case) -> trace (on L3 or L12 depending on case) and then what?  Does it just end in an open circuit?

In case 1 you don't need to worry about return path, I think, because GND on L2 is the same reference plane for L1 and L3.

In case 2 you don't have a parallel GND PTH via (or if you do you haven't told us about it), so how does GND get from L13 to L2 in this scenario?

If that's all correct, go ahead and update your question to include that detail and total trace len

Comment: @RobinIddon no it's not an open circuit. I have updated the same